# Ver actualizaciones hechas a una tabla en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, datatables, update

Tenia una query donde habia hecho actualizaciones a datos en una tabla, lastimosamente no logro encontrar aún esa query, no se si la elimine o se perdio cuando se reinicio mi laptop.

Saben de alguna query, o pasos a realizar para poder visualizar las actualizaciones hechas a una base de datos o tabla en SQL Server

Agradezco su ayuda desde ahora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No existe nada que esté activo por default. Puedes obtener algo de historia desde el caché

```
SELECT 
    qs.creation_time,
    qs.last_execution_time,
    st.text
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text( qs.sql_handle) AS st
WHERE text LIKE '%UPDATE%';
```

O tal vez tengas activo Query Store y se haya guardado ahí
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si quieres el código exacto que se ejecutó, es complicado obtenerlo si no tienes algún software que esté monitoreando toda la actividad de la base de datos.